# how to convert string to dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a long string that almost looks like a dictionary. I want to convert this to a proper Python dictionary. An example of the string is below:

```
'{"autorunResult":"0","batteryInfo":"No system battery","cpuBrand":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz","id":"bMlXyTrjXOOo","localeId":"1033","numCores":"1","payloadResult":"0","processorArchitecture":"x64 (AMD or Intel)","systemMemory":"0.2 GB","v":"5","windowsVersion":"Windows 7 Service Pack 1","payloadSaved":true,"autorunSaved":true,"installedApps":["AddressBook","Adobe AIR","com.adobe.mauby.4875E02D9FB21EE389F73B8D1702B320485DF8CE.1","Connection Manager","DirectDrawEx","Fontcore","IE40","IE4Data","IE5BAKEX","IEData","MobileOptionPack","Pillow-py2.7","SchedulingAgent","WIC","{00203668-8170-44A0-BE44-B632FA4D780F}","{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83217000FF}","{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170000}","{4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}","{77DCDCE3-2DED-62F3-8154-05E745472D07}","{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-A90000000001}","{BB8B979E-E336-47E7-96BC-1031C1B94561}","{C3CC4DF5-39A5-4027-B136-2B3E1F5AB6E2}"],"autoRunApps":["OptionalComponents","Adobe Reader Speed Launcher","SunJavaUpdateSched","MFDS"]}'
```

Note that this looks like a string representation of a dictionary. In fact, it is not. These two k,v pairs kill it:  `"payloadSaved":true,"autorunSaved":true`.   (no double-quotes around the values).

Basically, I need to take the long input string and convert it to a dictionary. Any tricks?

I tried:

1. using ast.literal_eval. It bombs...because of the above issue. Need to somehow sanitize the input string so that ast works.
2. Take out the parenthesis, tokenize the long string on comma, but again, it bombs...(the list values have commas...).

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: That's JSON, Python has a standard library module for that.

Comment: dang...did not think of that. thanks Jon!

Answer (score -1):

If that is JSON, then:

```
import json
d = json.loads(s)
```

If that is Python file:

```
d = eval(s)
```

For the string keys & values you will find no much difference. The difference may appear when `true/True` or `false/False` or `null/None` values appear, or on how the lists/dicts are serialized in some cases.